# Check if all arrays inside an array have a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Example array:

```
$items = array(
  array('sort': 1, 'name': 'name'),
  array('sort': 3, 'name': 'name'),
  array('sort': null, 'name': 'name')
);
```

I need to know if all child arrays have the `sort` key. If not, I'd manually create the sort via a for loop (and over-write the `sort` value for the ones that have it).

I'm already running a for loop, and I was thinking of adding another key such as `manual_sort` which I would equal to `index + 1`, and after the loop, if at least 1 array didn't have the `sort` key or if it's null), I'd use the `manual_sort` instead of the `sort` key (for example when looping the elements via the front-end or whatever usage the data has).

Also thought about doing a second loop to know whether or not `sort` should be overwritten.

These seems like dirty solutions though, any ideas?

My current code looks something like:

```
$db_sorted_items = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
  $items[$i]['name'] = ucfirst($items[$i]['name']);

  if (empty($items[$i]['sort']) {
    $db_sorted_items = false;
  }

  $items[$i]['number'] = $i + 1; // $i+1 because sort number starts at 1.
}

// err, gotta use `$items[$i]['number']` (or `sort` had all arrays had a positive `sort` key)
```

Comment: `count($myArray) == count(array_column($myArray, 'sort'))`

Comment: Thanks. I just added a challenge: dealing with `'sort': null`

Comment: Could you include the code where you say you are already doing a for loop on your nest of arrays? Just so its more clear.

Comment: `count($myArray) == count(array_filter(array_column($myArray, 'sort')))` will deal with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use array_column to get array for key 'sort'
// then use array_filter to remove null values
// then compare count 

if(count($array) == count(array_filter(array_column($array,'sort')))){
    echo 'All have valid sort key';
}else{
    echo 'No, few are missing';
}
```

In case if you want to have strict check, to make sure value corresponding to key `sort` is numeric then you may use below one, using `is_numeric`

```
if(count($array)==count(array_filter(array_column($array,'sort'),'is_numeric'))){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. I'd change it so it refreshes all `sort` attributes if it finds one object that doesn't have it, like this:

```
$db_sorted_items = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
  $items[$i]['name'] = ucfirst($items[$i]['name']);

  if ($db_sorted_items && empty($items[$i]['sort']) {
    $db_sorted_items = false;
    $i = -1; // Re-start for (the for will add 1 at the end)
  }else{
    $items[$i]['sort'] = $i + 1; // $i+1 because sort number starts at 1.
  }
}
```